# Polar coordinate limits for Definite integral of $\int_{a}^{\infty}t^2e^{t^2}$ dt

Tags: definite-integrals

Can anyone help me with this integral
$$I = \int_{a}^{\infty}t^2e^{-t^2} dt$$
$$I^2 = \int_{a}^{\infty}\int_{a}^{\infty}t^2h^2e^{-t^2-h^2} dt dh$$
Can you please explain how I can find the limits in the polar coordinates for the above integral? I am trying to do this similar to the way we evaluate the integral of Gauss distribution.

Comment: The use of polar coordinate is useful to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^{-t^2}dt}$, not for calculating the integral from $a$. In your case, you don't need to use polar coordinates, just use integration by parts

Comment: The Gaussian integral won't work here because of the different limits. See [upper and lower incomplete gamma functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html)